# what is the client side database lifetime ? do they last forever?

Tags: html, indexeddb

what is the lifetime of the client side database ?

Do they stay forever in the browser or does it some cleaning from time to time ?

I am using indexDB. What happen if i exeed the size allowed, should i do some cleaning scripts from time to time ?

Answer (score 0):

In chrome the storage stays forever unless the user is running low on storage space. Then some origins' client side databases are deleted. Yours may or may not be among the ones deleted.

If your origin tries to exceed the size allowed then your IDB transactions will fail with a QuotaError.